# Is there a limit on the number of words in bash command 'for file in words'?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am encountering strange behavior when executing the following bash script:

```
#! /bash/bin
dirs=$(ls .)
for dir in $dirs ; do
    files=$(ls $dir)
    for file in $files ; do
        line=$(head -n -1 $dir/$file)
        echo $line
    done
done
```

Instead of the echo of $line, I am getting the results of a ls / command, followed by the echo of $line, followed by the contents of $files.  My guess is that I am exceeding some limit in bash: I have 171 directories, each with 500 files.  When I add the line:

```
echo ${#line}
```

to the script, I get the right answer (68); but the echo of $line fills my terminal window.  What can I do now?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Using a wildcard directly (e.g. `for dir in *; do`) is much less prone to trouble from funny characters in filenames. Also, you should almost always double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$line"` instead of `echo $line`) for similar reasons.

Comment: Using wildcards directly doesn't change this behavior.

Comment: because of the nested for seems the script is trying to be recursive, maybe `find . -type f -exec head -n 1 {} +` could help, also the title doesn't match description

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to print all but the last line of all files one directory level down the current level? As comments suggest, **never parse the `ls` output**, it is for humans, not for automation. Use wildcards, instead:

```sh
for f in */*; do
  head -n -1 "$f"
done
```

However there are two potential issues:

- There are no such files. By default there will be one iteration of the loop with variable `f` set to literal value `*/*`. You can avoid this by enabling the `nullglob` option before the loop and disabling it again after the loop:

  ```sh
  shopt -s nullglob
  for f in */*; do
    head -n -1 "$f"
  done
  shopt -u nullglob
  ```
- Some "*files*" are not true files (links, directories...). But we can test this before executing `head`:

  ```sh
  shopt -s nullglob
  for f in */*; do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
      head -n -1 "$f"
    fi
  done
  shopt -u nullglob
  ```

As noted by @JohnKugelman there is simpler than a loop:

```sh
head -n -1 */*
```

But unfortunately there is no simple way to solve the second issue mentioned above. So, if you are not 100% sure that all files in `*/*` are really files, the loop with a test is safer...

... unless you use a dedicated utility like `find`:

```sh
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec head -n -1 {} \;
```

The `-type f` test retains only real files. The `-exec` action takes one argument which is a command to execute on each found file, where `{}` stands for the path of the current file. This command must be terminated by an escaped semicolon (`\;`).

Note: if you have thousands of files and you print their full content but the last line, it is not surprising that it "*fills your terminal window*". Just in case what you want is to print only the first line of these files, replace `head -n -1` by `head -n1`.

Comment: Or `head -qn -1 */*`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, absolutely, I'll add this to my answer. But the main drawback is that this fails if some of the "_files_" are not files.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably not related to the number of files and directories but to files that breaks the script behavior.
For example the script itself is a file which is not directory but will be listed in the first loop.
Any directory within the directories will also break the script.
Also notice the error in the first line which should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: There are no files or directories which break this script; correcting the error on the first line has no effect.